# Function is measurable if and only if it is constant a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measurable space with $\mu(X)=1$ and $\mu(A) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $A \in \Sigma$. Show that $f: X \to \mathbb R$ is $\mu-$ measurable if and only if $f$ is constant a.e..

I think I could show one implication:

Suppose $f$ is not constant, then $f$ takes at least to different values on two sets $A$, $B$ of measure greater than $0$. Note that $A \cap B=\emptyset$. So $1=\mu(A \cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)=2$, a contradiction.

I am not sure if my proof is correct and I got stuck trying to show the other implication:

Suppose $f$ is constant almost everywhere. I want to prove that $\{f>a\} \in \Sigma$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$. Let $E=\{x:f(x)\neq c\}$, then $E$ has measure zero by hypothesis.

$$\{f>a\}=\begin{cases}E^c \cup E \cap \{x:f(x)>a\},&\text{if }a< k\\E \cap \{x:f(x)>a\},&\text{if }a\geq k\;.\end{cases}$$

If $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is complete, it follows that $f$ is measurable, but if not I don't see why $E \cap \{x:f(x)>a\} \in \Sigma$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\sum = \{ \emptyset, X, E, E^c\}$, then there is no reason for $f$ to be measurable. So yes, you need the measure to be complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proof of the first direction looks fine.

The opposite direction is false unless you have a complete measure, and it's pretty easy to construct a counterexample.

Suppose that

$X = \{1,2,3\}$, $\sum = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, X\}$, $\mu(\{2,3\}) = 0$.

$f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 2$, $f(3) = 3$ is $\mu$-a.e. constant function, but note that

$\{ f > 2\} =\{3\}$ doesn't belong to the sigma algebra.

So completeness is necessary for the direction you are trying to prove.